# Alternative versions of SVN subversion on one Linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn

I work on Ubuntu with several *svn* java repositories and they have different versions of *svn* (I can't update *svn* version on server side). 
So is it possible to install old subversion version (1.6, 1.7) from zip archive and change svn version when needed?

I do that for *java  1.6/1.7/1.8* with *update-alternatives*, is it possible for *svn*?
And how properly and where to install Subversion from zip file?